# Matsui's paper on Linear Cryptanalysis of DES

Tags: des, linear-cryptanalysis

I am trying to derive the best linear approximation for one round DES.

I read the question and answer

[Regarding matsui's Paper on Linear Cryptanalysis of DES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/regarding-matsuis-paper-on-linear-cryptanalysis-of-des)

several times but still could not figure out the part

"
y_3y_2y_1y_0 can be propagated to bits 7, 18, 24 and 29 of the output of the round function, this time taking into account the effect of the bit permutation P(.) 
"

The output of S box #5 is Y[13], Y[14], Y[15] and Y[16] (when counting from right). And after permutation these bits would be Y[26], Y[20], Y[10] and Y[1] respectively. I could not find the desired bit number i.e. F(X,K)_7, F(X,K)_18, ...

Answer (score 1):

Confusion is from notation differences between standard DES notation and Matsui's notation. After reading this: [Matsui's Linear attack on DES P box](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25305/matsuis-linear-attack-on-des-p-box)
and make some rearrangements I can find the solution.